# Understanding Todoist-API

Tags: python, api, todoist

I am trying to use the Todoist-API for Python. I found the [official docs](https://developer.todoist.com/) on the internet and downloaded the [GitHub-Repo](https://github.com/Doist/todoist-python). Unfortunately I don't get out how to add a new task.

I do the normal login:

```
api = todoist.TodoistAPI(XYZ)
api.sync
```

Then I try to add a new task:

```
item = api.items.add('Task1')
```

It tells me I have to give two arguments: name and project_id:

```
item = api.items.add('Task1', 128501470)
```

Does anyone know where I could get all my projects IDs? I just want to use the Inbox-Project (default).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with this specific API, but considering you're using this api: https://github.com/doist/todoist-python, you can probably do something like:

```
response = api.sync()
projects = response['projects']
for project in projects: 
   print(project['name'] + '-' + project['id'])
```

Basically printing all the names and id's

Answer (score 0):

Just open Todoist in a web browser and look at the address bar, it's right after "project", I beleive you need to truncate the first three or 4 characters though, click through a few projects and you'll see the project id's change.

Answer (score 0):

To add them to the inbox the easiest way is to do the following:

```
    from todoist.api import TodoistAPI

    apiToken = 'your token"
    todoist: TodoistAPI = TodoistAPI(api_token)
    response = todoist.add_item("Item1")
    todoist.sync()
    todoist.commit()
```

You will have to refresh either the web page or your app to immediately see the new item